# How to generate urls without pathname in a Symfony project

Tags: php, url, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Using a routing rule in a Symfony project the function `link_to` (or `url_for`) generates an url like `mydomain.com/myproject/web/friendly-name.html` or `mydomain.com/web/friendly-name.html`
There is a smart way, **alternative to write own helper**, to generate urls without `/myproject/web` or `/web` keeping the choosen directory structure.

**Updating**

Finally I found the solution in the answer to this question: [symfony on virtual host document root problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359756/symfony-on-virtual-host-document-root-problem)

Comment: Duplicated maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073121/remove-web-from-symfony-1-4-path-on-shared-hosting and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799050/htaccess-for-symfony-on-shared-hosting

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No duplicated, I'm not looking for url rewriting.
As written in "The Definitive Guide to Symfony", the routing system does two things:
    * It interprets the external URL of incoming requests and transforms it into an internal URI, to determine the module/action and the request parameters.
    * It formats the internal URIs used in links into external URLs (provided that you use the link helpers).
I'm looking for the second thing, the url generation.

Answer (score 0):

just point your webserver Document Root to /web Directory.

This is the right way of integrating symfony1.4.

Cheers malte

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we have just the hosting web, we can't change the document root, pointing the webserver directly into /myproject/web or /web. So I'm looking for generating urls without /myproject/web or /web. Then of course the url rewriting, through .htaccess, is the way to provide to the routing system the right url.